# Como trabalhar com session no angular / jquery

Tags: php, angular, session

Estou desenvolvendo um site onde preciso armazenar na seção alguns dados como pesquisas realizadas.

Optamos por desenvolver o from do sistema em angular/jquery. Em php eu vi que existem as sessions. Essas sessions guarda os dados no servidor, certo?

Existe alguma forma similar com que o angular/jquery trataria isso? Vejo que guardar esses tipos de dados no localStorage seria poluitivo, portanto fico em dúvida se utilizar Angular ou JQuery conseguiria atingir algo semelhante que seria feito usando o blade.

Gostaria de concluir perguntando se o Angular/JQuery são boas ferramentas pra esse tipo de aplicação (um marketplace, por exemplo).

Comment: Por que fica poluitivo? Se tem armazenamento livre o suficiente, por que não usar? Na verdade geralmente é preferível, ao armazenar isso no browser, diminui os recursos usados do servidor. Mas se **há alguma vantagem** e esse consumo de recursos no servidor não será um problema, pode usar as sessões. Em relação a sua pergunta,  depende do que seu marketplace precisa ter, quais são os pré requisitos?

Answer (score -1):

Você pode usar o localStorage ou sessionStorage
Exemplo:

```
localStorage.setItem('dados', '{name:"railson", idade:26}');
```

e pra recuperar basta:

```
localStorage.getItem('dados');
```

A diferença do locao storage pro session é q o session se fecha a aba do navegador você perde os dados, o local fica la ate vc excluir.